# "Thank you, Lord, for the teachers (those) who care for me"

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

> 1. Thank you, Lord, for the teachers those who care for me.
> 2. Thank you, Lord, for the teachers who care for me.

Which of these two would be more correct?

Comment: Relative clauses modify their antecedent noun phrase, which is _teachers_ in this case; there would be no use for a pronoun _those_,a which already means _teachers_. It is also possible to have a relative clause modifying an indefinite pronoun, like _those who help us_, which means "the people who help us". But you wouldn't say **The teachers the people who help us*.

Comment: @JohnLawler - you may wish to post that as an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 3):

## Short Answer

> **#2 is correct.** *Thank you, Lord, for the teachers who care for me.*
>
> **#1 is incorrect.** *Thank you, Lord, for the teachers <strike>those</strike> who care for me.*

Also correct would be:

3. *Thank you, Lord, for those who care for me.*
4. *Thank you, Lord, for those teachers who care for me.*

### Explanation

In #1, "those" in is redundant to the word "teachers."

In #4, "those" modifies "teachers" and is not redundant to "teachers." This is because in #4, "those" functions as an **adjective** and modifies "teachers." It tells us which specific subset of teachers out of the entire universe of teachers. Whereas, in #1, "those" would be a (redundant) **pronoun**. And, therefore, incorrect.

Note: "Those" is the plural form of "that" and [you can see in this dictionary link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/that?s=t) that "that" can serve as many different parts of speech. Including pronouns, adjectives and several others.